# error while trying to get build ios using xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am new to IOS development, I tried to build ios using Xcode but it's getting an error:

> Failed uploading cSYMs due to error: Error
> Domain=com.twitter.FABCompoundOperation.error Code=4294967293 "(null)"
> UserInfo={com.twitter.FABCompoundOperation.error.user-info-key.underlying-errors=(

I searched google but can't get a clear idea, can someone help me to resolve this issue with step by step guidance?